# MVC EF Core - Collection doesn't get FK from master table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core MVC using EF Core 6, Master-Detail on one page, it gives error on saving.

In `[HttpGet]Create()` I add 3 details (Experiences) to master (Applicant) and set their PKs (1,2,3).

In `[HttpPost]Create(applicant)` applicant.Experiences[1,2,3].ExperienceId = 0 (PKs are lost) and applicant.Experiences[1,2,3].ApplicantId = 0 (FK is not correct, it should be 9 as applicant.id = 9).

other master and detail data entered by user are correct.

I use "EF Core Power Tools" to generate the model.

also, is this the correct way to do Master-Detail on one page? can you please refer to any demo/example of this type?

Thanks for help.

**Controller**

```
 public class ResumeController : Controller
    {
     private readonly ResumeDBContext _context;

        public ResumeController(ResumeDBContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Applicant> applicants;
            applicants = _context.Applicants.ToList();

            return View(applicants);
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            Applicant applicat = new Applicant();
            applicat.Experiences.Add (new Experience() { ExperienceId = 1 });
            applicat.Experiences.Add(new Experience() { ExperienceId = 2 });
            applicat.Experiences.Add(new Experience() { ExperienceId = 3 });

            return View(applicat);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(Applicant applicant)
        {
            _context.Add(applicant); //applicant.Experiences[].ExperiencId = 0 //PK
                                     //applicant.Experiences[].ApplicantId = 0 //FK

            _context.SaveChanges();  //Raise Exception System.InvalidOperationException: 
//'The instance of entity type 'Experience' cannot be tracked 
//because another instance with the same key value for {'ExperienceId'} 
//is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that
// only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. 
//Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' 
//to see the conflicting key values.'

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

    }
```

**Model**

```
public partial class Applicant
    {
        public Applicant()
        {
            Experiences = new List<Experience>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Experience> Experiences { get; set; }
    }
public partial class Experience
    {
        public int ExperienceId { get; set; }
        public int ApplicantId { get; set; }
        public string FieldName { get; set; }

        public virtual Applicant Applicant { get; set; }
    }
```

**View**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Id" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                        </th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Experiences.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Experiences[i].FieldName, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The error indicates you've tracked Experience some where else,for example(var exps=_context.Experience.ToList()).What's the lifetime of your dbcontext?Scoped or Singleton?

Comment: i got dbcontext via D.Injection (builder.Services.AddDbContext<ResumeDBContext>)
i have update code of controller to show this. what i post is the whole program (i want it to be simple so i can identity the problem). in create method i add new experiences to applicant and bind them in view. `applicat.Experiences.Add (new Experience() { ExperienceId = 1 });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't registed the dbcontext as Singleton service as below:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DbDataContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(......),ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
```

Also haven't load Experience Entity before this Line in same controller:

```
_context.Add(applicant);
```

As far as I known,the only possible mistake you may make is that you disabled
automatic generation for primary keys somewhere,then when you track the Experience entities both have the default value 0 for PK,the error occored.

Reproduced the error on myside:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Experience>().Property(e => e.ExperienceId).ValueGeneratedNever();
    }
```

[image]

You should enable automatic  generation for primary keys for the entities don't have PK,if you don't want automatic  generation,you have to set the PK in your C# codes before tracking the entity

Here's the documents related with [load related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/),[save related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data),[configuring value generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#explicitly-configuring-value-generation) ,hopes help

Comment: Thanks for your great help.  I use "EF Core Power Tools" to generate the model and it adds .ValueGeneratedNever() automatically.  I already add PK to every experience in [HttpGet] Create method : `applicat.Experiences.Add (new Experience() { ExperienceId = 1 });` but i thought that binding mechanism will add them after re-instantiate them on [HttpPost] Create,. My assumption was not correct.  The next lines of code will solve the problem :

Comment: `int x = 1;

            foreach (var item in applicant.Experiences)
            {
                item.ExperienceId = x;
                x =  x + 1;
            }
            _context.Add(applicant);
            _context.SaveChanges();`